# Why is a inviscid flow assumed to involve no thermal conduction and mass diffusion?

Tags: thermal-conduction

I can understand how the assumption of inviscid flow leads to Reynolds Number (Re) tending to infinity. But how does the assumption of inviscid flow lead to the assumption of no thermal conduction and mass diffusion?
I would think Re tending to infinity would imply higher turbulence mixing, so higher heat transfer.
Does the assumption of no thermal conduction mean no heat transfer OR that there is no heat transfer due to conduction (may be due to very high convective heat transfer)?

Not sure how to interpret the assumption of no thermal conductivity for a inviscid flow.

Source:
Ref 1: Flight (Aerodynamics), John D. AndersonJr. in https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/inviscid-flow
[image]

Ref 2: Modern Compressible Flow, John D Anderson

Comment: You can't have turbulence without viscosity.

Comment: Please give a source, so readers can understand the context and assumptions. There are many fluid flow analyses, with various assumptions.

Comment: @D.Halsey It is my understanding as long as there is something to trip the flow turbulence can be generated in inviscid fluid.  Turbulence won't be developed on its own due to the velocity gradient. But once preset, vorticity wont be dissipated

Comment: @Chemomechanics Sure I have added it.

Comment: Thank you. Short sketch to avoid writing all the terms: "Inviscid flow" is a term used to describe fluid flow obeying the [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_\(fluid_dynamics\)). The corresponding energy equation, for example, lacks the [thermal conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction) term $k\nabla^2 T$. One way of satisfying this absence is to assume that $k=0$. Similar arguments can be made for the other assumptions.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you. That is helpful! Can you please tell what is the rational for assuming conductivity is zero in Euler equation. Any material on the same?

Comment: The lack of any [heat-equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)-related terms in the [Euler energy-balance equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Euler_equations).

Comment: @Chemomechanics In the wiki page the zero conductivity is already assumed in the beginning without any explanation "In particular, they correspond to the Navier–Stokes equations with zero viscosity and zero thermal conductivity." In the section you have linked to, they are considering the compressible euler eq for energy and there is no conductivity (diffusive term) either. Why is k considered zero? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: ie why is there no diffusive term in the energy eq?

Comment: A Wikipedia page isn't a mathematical proof, building up from basic assumptions; it's a(n ideally self-consistent) description of the framework. Equation simplification is its own motivation to ignore terms, as long as the predictions reasonably match reality. The fluid is also assumed to have zero electric and magnetic susceptibility, for that matter, although these aren't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I have the answer to my question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/physical-interpretation-of-the-change-of-diffusion-term-in-navier-stokes-equatio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical interpretation of the change of diffusion term in navier stokes equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/physical-interpretation-of-the-change-of-diffusion-term-in-navier-stokes-equatio)